# WIX Approach re Features

Tags: wix

I've got a Windows service, that uses DLLs. I can stop the service, replace the DLLs, and start the service again, which is simpler than a full upgrade.  I know I can make 2 different installers, one for the service and one for the DLLs, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant approach, possibly with using two features.

I'm unsure about the best approach to take.  What do you think?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with one MSI package, and it's not clear to me why you think having two features is a solution. So assuming the problem you want to solve is updating the Dlls, having separate features doesn't help, having a separate MSI setup gives you two entries in Programs&Features and issues with customers having two separate product MSIs to deal with for no good reason.

A major upgrade IS the elegant solution, WiX has a major upgrade element, it can stop the service and upgrade everything and is generally reliable. Or you can build a patch to update the Dlls if you want, but that's not usually worth it unless the product has a large number of files and you want a quick update to just a couple of files, and patches can be tricky if you are not familiar with Windows Installer.